# Which item drops are available without buying any passes?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I have finally decided to pick up Counter-Strike GO a few days ago.
I've read up on the item drop system, but am still a bit confused and would love to read a detailed breakdown of which items are available as random drops from the get-go, without buying any of the operations passes.

From what I gather, these items are available from the beginning as drops (on community/VAC secured servers):

- Classic cases
- eSports cases
- Community Skins cases
- Weapon skins *(is there a list of which ones are dropped as loose skins? I heard StatTrak weapons never become available without opening cases?)*
- Sticker capsules *(but loose stickers are never awarded separately?)*

The operations passes only add the specific operations cases and missions to the rewards system for more variety, but does not increase the frequency of drops, correct?
I know you can only receive 3-6 items per week, chances dropping with increased playtime, and resetting once a week.

Apologies for yet another question about the item system, but I can't really find any concise explanation and haven't gotten any drops yet. I'm also debating on whether or not I should buy the passes, or (for the time being) make due with the items that are available from the start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For item drops, it boils down to 3 categories:

1. **Weapons**

   - Individual skins that drop are parts of certain Collections

     - [A year ago-ish several of the original weapon collection skins were retired, meaning you cannot receive them as a drop from the item-drop system](http://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/2013/11/8199/)
     - Collections that you can currently receive item-drops from

       - [The Train Collection](http://csgostash.com/?collection=The%20Train%20Collection)
       - [The Mirage Collection](http://csgostash.com/?collection=The%20Mirage%20Collection)
       - [The Safehouse Collection](http://csgostash.com/?collection=The%20Safehouse%20Collection)
       - [The Italy Collection](http://csgostash.com/?collection=The%20Italy%20Collection)
       - [The Lake Collection](http://csgostash.com/?collection=The%20Lake%20Collection)
       - [The Dust II Collection](http://csgostash.com/?collection=The%20Dust%202%20Collection)
       - [The Bank Collection](http://csgostash.com/?collection=The%20Bank%20Collection)
   - Weapons originating from Cases cannot be found as a drop
   - StatTrak weapons cannot be found as a drop
2. **Cases & Capsules**

   - There are always 3-5 cases in rotation in the item drop system
   - As new cases come in, old cases are phased out.
   - Some cases are for Operation pass-holders

     - For instance, the current operation is called [Operation Breakout](http://www.counter-strike.net/operationbreakout), with a case called [Operation Breakout Case](http://csgostash.com/?collection=The+Breakout+Collection)
     - This means that the Operation Breakout Case will drop for only for Operation Breakout pass holders
   - Older Operation drops are available to anyone, but this usually up to Valve's discretion

     - The previous Operation, [Operation Phoenix](http://www.counter-strike.net/operationphoenix/), had it's own case specific for its own passholders, called the [Operation Phoenix Case](http://csgostash.com/?collection=The%20Phoenix%20Collection)
     - The Operation Phoenix case used to be only for passholders, but can now be received as an item drop by anyone
   - Sticker Capsules can drop
   - Exclusive Sticker Capsules cannot drop. For example, the [Katowice 2014 Challengers](http://csgostash.com/stickers.php?capsule=EMS%20Katowice%202014%20Challengers) capsule (had to be bought in-game)
3. **Missions**

   - This was introduced in Operation Breakout
   - Missions WILL not drop for players without the Operation Breakout Pass
   - Completing a mission will give you a weapon drop from 3 specific collections:

     - The [Baggage Collection](http://csgostash.com/?collection=The%20Baggage%20Collection)
     - The [Overpass Collection](http://csgostash.com/?collection=The%20Overpass%20Collection)
     - The [Cobblestone Collection](http://csgostash.com/?collection=The%20Cobblestone%20Collection)
     - This means the above 3 colletion weapons CANNOT be found through regular item-drop system